# Anchor Tooltip not showing up

Tags: tooltip, anchor

I have a link in my page for which I want to change the text displayed when the user hovers over the link:

```
<a id="mylink" runat="server" onmouseover="javascript:ShowAssignments();" onmouseout="javascript:HideAssignments();" title="Click here to assign"></a>

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "doShowAssignments", "<script type='text/javascript'>function ShowAssignments() { try { if (document.all) { document.all('" + lbnShowTemplateInfo.ClientID + "').click(); } else { document.getElementById('" + lbnShowTemplateInfo.ClientID + "').click(); } } catch(e){} } </script>");


protected void lbnShowTemplateInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // get list of assignments formatted as string from a datatable
  string templateAssignment = GetAssignment(dtTemplateAssignments, "Template");
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(templateAssignment))
  {
      templateAssignment = "Assigned to: " + templateAssignment;
      lnkCurrentAssignments.InnerHtml = templateAssignment;
  }
  else
  {
      lnkCurrentAssignments.InnerHtml = "Assign";
  }
```

}

The ShowAssignments method triggers some C# code, but my problem is that there is no tooltip displayed and it seems like my page is loading continuously while the mouse is over this link.

How can I prevent this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you give the code for `ShowAssignments()` as well?

Comment: I edited my post to include the C# code also.

Comment: I'm sorry, I honestly don't know about the JavaScript-C# interaction. Does this page do AJAX requests back to the server? Otherwise, you could post the page source to a place like [here](http://jsfiddle.net).